# Is a 40 minute layover time between flights at the Munich airport on two Lufthansa flights enough?

Tags: international-travel, short-connections, lufthansa, muc

My family is leaving 5/21 from DTW in the United States to travel to Venice to board a cruise ship the afternoon of 5/23.  We are considering booking a Lufthansa two stop flight from DTW to Munich that only has a 40 minute layover to catch the next flight to Venice.  Is 40 minutes enough time to make the flight to Venice?  What else should we be considering as we plan for this first stop in Munich?

Comment: If Lufthansa sells you this they obviously think it is possible. You will need to pass immigration in Munich, but your luggage will be checked through to Venice.

Comment: I suppose you mean two legs rather than two stops?

Comment: I suppose you are talking about DTW-MUC 17:35 - 07:45+1 and MUC-VCE 08:25 - 09:25. Probably a lot of international flights arriving at that time of day, and the second flight uses an RJ-195 so probably a bus and an early boarding. It is also not operated by Lufthansa but by Air Dolomiti (though it is marketed by LH). The good news is that there are 4 other flights on that route the same day, so you probably won't wait long if you miss your initially planned flight.

Comment: This might help: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/152472/is-a-2hr-transit-enough-time-in-munich-from-canada

Answer (score 2):

40 minutes would be very tight for this connection. Munich is your first port of entry into the Schengen area so you will need to go through immigration control in Munich. Depending on your citizenship and time of day, that can take some extra time.

If Lufthansa is willing to sell you this as a single ticket, it's a legal connection an you have a decent chance of making it. But there is no room for error: if anything goes wrong, is delayed or just a little longer than usual, you will miss it. If you do miss it, LH will rebook you on the next available flight for free, but you may miss your cruise, so I would advice against this.

There is NO WAY you can make this with two separate tickets.

Comment: As I understand it, OP flies MUC-VCE on the 22nd while the cruise departs on the 23rd. Plenty of opportunities to get to VCE in time even if the original flight is missed.

Comment: Why should 40 minutes be 'very tight'? Lufthansa operates with a minimum connection time of only 30 minutes for non-schengen to schengen transfers in Munich and have according to their own statement scheduled the most common transfers to be in the range 35-60 minutes. If the connection is really tight, you will get priority in the immigration queue.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Come on... Just the time to deplane, walk to the people mover (flight is likely to arrive at L gates), wait for it, get to passport control, queue up a little, go through security (I suppose), walk to the gate... You need to have stars pretty well aligned to do that in the 20 minutes or so before boarding closes (it's a bus gate), especially if "family" means small children.

Comment: @jcaron If the transfer is very tight, I would not be surpised if already the staff in the aircraft arranged for you to be the first to deplane and you might even be taken from gate to gate by ground staff at the airport. If you miss the flight from Munich, you will likely arrive more than 3 hours delayed in Venice, even if you are moved to the next available flight, and Lufthansa will be liable for a hefty €600 delay compensation per passenger. That ought to be incentive enough not to sell unrelastic connections or even to give some extra support during transfer if necessary.

Comment: @jcaron Tor-Einar is right. When I had a delayed arrival on a tight connection at Vienna once, with both incoming and outgoing flights at remote stands, I (and two others in my position) were given to an airline employee with a car who drove us to an immigration control desk and thence to our departing plane. No people mover, no running through the terminal. I would be surprised if the same doesn't happen in Munich. For less urgent connections, an airline employee may rush passengers to the priority immigration queue; I've also experienced that firsthand in a couple of different airports.